# get notify when predictive is hidden by user in IOS

Tags: ios

subject:

for ios 8 i need some notification when if i hide the word predictive by swipe down the predictive view
i required notification for both predictive ON/OFF.can u pl give some idea?

my try:

i did the frame up and down for seperating ios 7 / 8. but when i hide the word predictive by swipe down the predictive view, my text view still in up frame it did get down..

this is my code

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] floatValue]>=8.0f)
{

    ChatViewBottomTool.frame = CGRectMake(screenArea.origin.x, screenArea.size.height-310, screenArea.size.width,44);
    ChatViewTable.frame = CGRectMake(ChatViewTable.frame.origin.x, ChatViewTable.frame.origin.y, screenArea.size.width,  screenArea.size.height-372);
    [ChatViewBottomTool sizeToFit];

    }else{

    ChatViewBottomTool.frame = CGRectMake(screenArea.origin.x, screenArea.size.height-280, screenArea.size.width,44);
    ChatViewTable.frame = CGRectMake(ChatViewTable.frame.origin.x, ChatViewTable.frame.origin.y, screenArea.size.width,  screenArea.size.height-342);
    [ChatViewBottomTool sizeToFit];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` to get correct keyboard frame:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)  name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification  object:self.view.window];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    double duration = [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
            // Do something with keyboard frame with same animation duration
    }];
}
```